# TEventObject and WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, idispatch

I created a `TEventObject` to provide `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseMove` events for `TWebBrowser`.  The events work perfectly when moving the mouse and when clicking in the webbrowser, but when I scroll or click the webbrowser's vertical scrollbar a `EZeroDivide` exception ocurs.  EurekaLog reports a EZeroDivide exception in d2d1.dll.  I tried to trap the exception but nothing I have tried seems to work:

```
function TEventObject.Invoke( DispID: integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: integer; Flags: Word; var Params;
  VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer ): HResult;
begin
  try
    if ( DispID = DISPID_VALUE ) then
    begin
      if Assigned( FOnEvent ) then
        FOnEvent;
      Result := S_OK;
    end
    else
    begin
      FOnEvent := nil;
      Result := E_NOTIMPL;
    end;
  except
    on EZeroDivide do
    begin
      FOnEvent := nil;
      Result := E_NOTIMPL;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

My question is can I prevent the exception somehow or can mousedown on the TWebbrowser vertical scrollbar be detected to prevent the exception?  This exception is a difficult one for me to solve because I do not know much about TEventObject and I do not understand why the exception only ocurs when clicking or dragging the vertical scrollbar.  I can provide more infomation if needed.  Compiler: Delphi 2010.

**[Edit]**
See this post:
http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/0/waArticleBookmark.7401953
A very simple demo app is available at:
 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2167512/bugs/ie9/ie9_bug.zip

This prevents the bug:

```
Math.SetExceptionMask([exInvalidOp, exDenormalized, exZeroDivide,exOverflow, exUnderflow, exPrecision]);
```

Comment: d2d1.dll is a part of MS Direct2D

Comment: Possible duplicate http://gastonx.net/?p=10 :D

Comment: @kobik, funny is that Google translator detects the language as Swedish :) Anyway +1; it seems that no one from MS has fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to disable FPU exceptions:

```
System.Set8087CW($133F);
```

In the newer versions of Delphi:

```
Math.SetExceptionMask([exInvalidOp, exDenormalized, exZeroDivide, exOverflow, exUnderflow, exPrecision]);
```

Comment: Thank-you very much. SetExceptionMask prevents the exception... See my edit.  Can there be side effects from this?

Comment: Yeah and all of them in whole application.

Comment: I had a long [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200581/twebbrowser-crashes-with-embedded-youtube-clips) about this issue. my conclusion is that there are no side effects.

Comment: @TLama - What do you mean "Yeah and all of them in whole application"... not a good idea to use SetExceptionMask?

Comment: @Bill, nothing more than if you divide somewhere in your application by 0 you won't get the exception. And that [`KB2488113`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=982) update I have already on my computer so nothing is fixed. What to say, just MS :)