# VLC PLayer error when clicking on volume

Tags: delphi, vlc, delphi-xe5

I am using VLC on my Delphi application. But I'm having problems with the PLAYER.
I add a stream , when I click the volume, it simply crashes the program :
ALL application stopped working

You can correct this with Delphi programming? or is it the application that is in trouble?

```
procedure TForm4.OnShowCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
VLCPlugin1.addTarget(form3.edit1.text,null, VLCPlayListInsert, 0);
VLCPlugin1.play;
end;
```

Can I remove the volume from the player ?

Comment: What version of the plugin? What version of Windows? Does it work if you change the volume via code?

Comment: Also, setting the caption, left, and top shouldn't be relevant to the question, and should be removed from the question.

Comment: I had exactly this problem a few days ago and am obliged to @kobik for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742778/automating-videolans-vlc-using-delphi

Comment: Thanks, worked properly . ATT